# How do I pass my $JBOSS_HOME environment variable into my Maven script?

Tags: maven, environment-variables, maven-3

I'm using Mac 10.9.5 with maven 3.2.3.  I have defined an environment variable, `$JBOSS_HOME`, in my `~/.profile` file, which is accessible through my shell.  Is there a way, using `MAVEN_OPTS`, or similar, that I can reference this value in a Maven antrun plugin?  The following is the relevant part of my plugin ...

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>create-dodeploy-file</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    <echo
                        file="$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments/${project.artifactId}.war.dodeploy"
                        append="false" message="" />
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

I would prefer to do this in such a way that I don't have to pass a command line to Maven upon each invocation (e.g. `-DJBOSS_HOME=$JBOSS_HOME`. If there were some system way I could tell Maven about this environment var, that would be the best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `env.` to refer to environment variables in your `pom.xml`:

```
<properties>
    <JBOSS_HOME>${env.JBOSS_HOME}</JBOSS_HOME>
</properties>

<!-- plugin declaration, snipped -->

<echo
    file="${JBOSS_HOME}/standalone/deployments/${project.artifactId}.war.dodeploy"
    append="false" message="" />
```